# Javascript Skipping Adjacent Value as Undefined

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I'm trying to write a program that looks for perfect and *almost perfect* numbers.

```
var num = readline();

function sumDivisors(num){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < num; i++){
    if (!(num % i)) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  if ( sum == num ) {
     print(num + " perfect");
   }
  if ( (sum - num == 2) || (sum - num == -2) ) {
     print(num + " almost perfect");
   }
  if ( ( sum != num ) && (sum - num != 2) && (sum - num != -2) ) {
     print(num + " not perfect");
   }
  while(readline()){
     sumDivisors(readline());
   }
}

print(sumDivisors(num));
```

It accepts a number of inputs from the user, and outputs *perfect* for perfect numbers, *almost perfect* for almost perfect numbers, and *not perfect* for... well, you get it.

**Sample Input/Output**

[image]

**My Question:**

I'm almost there. The code above seems to work, except for one thing. The while loop skips adjacent values and marks them as `undefined`.

For example, when I input 6,43,2,650,28, the output will be 6 - perfect, [43 will be skipped], 2 - not perfect, [650 will be skipped], 28 - perfect, `undefined`.

**Problematic Output**

[image]

Comment: too many `readline()` calls

`while(var num = readline()){
     sumDivisors(num);
   }`

Comment: Thanks. Using `while(var num = readline()){ sumDivisors(num); }` gives me a syntax error. Replacing that with `for(var num; num = readline();) { 
sumDivisors(num);  }` gives me the correct answer but with `undefined` at the end. I'm thinking its because its finding an empty line at the end. Any work around you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `readline()` twice in each loop:

```
while(readline()){          // <-- here
   sumDivisors(readline()); // <-- again here
}
```

Since you aren't doing anything with the first one, it's just removing the number from the list. An easy fix is to save the result in the `while()` test:

```
while((n = readline())){
   sumDivisors(n);
}
```

or better yet:

```
if((n = readline())){ // <-- you don't need a loop here since you have recursion
   sumDivisors(n);
}
```

You are also calling `print` on `sumDivisors()` which doesn't return anything: `print(sumDivisors(num));` This is why you are getting the `undefined` line in your output.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just have to optimise my code now. It's supposed to run in under a second, and it exceeds that right now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
while(readline()){
  sumDivisors(readline());
}
```

This part is the problem. You read a line to test whether it's the end, *discard that line*, and if it's not, you read the next line to process. Save the result and use that line to sum your divisors.

You will also have a very weird behaviour because of the recursion inside a loop. I suggest you extract the loop into one function, which calls another function which only deals with one line:

```
function findPerfectionInNumbers() {
  let line;
  while (line = readline()) {
    checkNumberForPerfection(line);
  }
}
```

and you do no recursion inside that other function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate all the way to the target number. It's just fine to go up to half of it, `Math.floor(n/2)`. Also there are no odd perfect numbers so you may iterate only the evens. Yet since you check for almost perfects as well i pass this time saver. Accordingly you may do as follows;

```js
function isPerfect(n){
  var target = Math.floor(n/2),
      sum    = Array.from({length: target})
                    .reduce((s,_,i) => n%(i+1) ? s : s += i+1, 0);
  return sum === n ? "perfect number"
                   : Math.abs(sum-n) < 3 ? "almost perfect number"
                                         : "not a perfect number";
}

console.log(isPerfect(33550336));
```

Comment: Wow, very clever. I'll try this, might save me some load time. Thanks

Comment: @kwangonya Thank you, but keep in mind that this is still just a practice of coding to calculate the perfect numbers.. In real life you wouldn't use this because [there are very few perfect numbers](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51516.html) like 15 or so... and you can just keep them in a Map object to compare with the input. :)